# Flask-Login - Remember Me working automatically

Tags: flask, flask-login

I am writing a simple login page using `flask-login` and trying to implement *Remember Me* functionality.

To my surprise *Remember Me* is working automatically without setting the `remember=True` in the `login_user` function and when i close the browser after logging in and then re-open it again, my login session persists.

I even tried setting `remember=False` explicitly but still the login persists the browser closing. Below is how my view looks like

```
@app.route("/login", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    form = LoginForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        user = User.query.filter_by(username=form.username.data).first()
        if user is not None and user.verify_password(form.password.data):
            if form.remember_me.data:
                 login_user(user, remember=True, duration=timedelta(days=5))
            else:
                login_user(user)
                # login_user(user, remember=False) 
            flash('Successful Login', 'success')
            next_url = request.args.get('next')
            if not next_url or url_parse(next_url).netloc != '':
                return redirect(url_for("thankyou"))
            return redirect(next_url)
        else:
            flash('Incorrect Username or Password', 'danger')
            form.username.data = ''
            form.password.data = ''
    return render_template("login.html", form=form)
```

Am i missing something or there is something wrong with my implementation ? I have tested this with both chrome and firefox and on both same thing happens which is if i just close the browser without logging out my login persists.

**Edit #1**

I looked more into it and it seems that the session cookie persists if I close my browser and then open it again. Is this the default behavior ?

**Edit #2**

After some more digging into it I found that flask by default makes the session permanent so you need to explicitly set to `False`, this seems to fix that session being persisted problem but now the problem is it deletes the `remember_token` cookie as well.

```
@app.before_request
def make_session_permanent():
    session.permanent = False
```

Comment: May be your browser is still running in background? is it chrome?

Comment: yes.. Ahh.. got it.. I was creating new window from existing chromw window.. thanks for the hint,

Comment: @ChienNguyen no it still does not work. So if i login and then close the browser and then launch the browser i can see my login persists. i have tried this with both chrome and firefox

Comment: @Rohit. You don't need to set "session.permanent = False", all you need to do is set "login_user(user, remember=True)" so that when you close the browser and open it again it will remember the page, if you set it to "login_user(user, remember=False)", it cannot remember it and your user will be required to login.